# Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a frame with origin Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my parent window code

```
    var host = document.domain;
        var client_api_key='43415795136947951'; 

    $("#load_pdf").on("click",function(){
    var popup;
    popup = window.open("http://editsoftsolutions.com/amarujala/developer/apilogin.php  ?host="+host+"&client_api_key="+client_api_key, "new        window",'height=400,width=500,left=400,top=200,\n\
    //resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,\n\
    //directories=no, status=yes');
           popup.focus();

           return false

     });
    function getdata(data)
    {
    alert(data); 
    }
```

http://azeemkhan.me/Dev/loginwithsso.php

then i open new window and allow for accessing data there is an error

```
 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://editsoftsolutions.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://azeemkhan.me". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

and this is child window code

```
   

           if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {

           var jArray = ;

           userdata =JSON.stringify(jArray); 
           window.opener.getdata(userdata);
           }

           window.close();
```

Comment: that child window code has a syntax error

Comment: user name manlodhi1985@gmail.com   and password is 111111

Comment: but it run on same domain correctly

Comment: http://editsoftsolutions.com/amarujala/loginwithsso.php        you can check it on this link